# ethminer not picking up Radeon R9 RX 480

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, ethminer, gpu

I hope someone can help.

My system has 3 GPUs, one that sits on the motherboard and two RX 480s that I added for mining purposes.

[image: Results from --list-devices]

I've installed the latest AMD drivers (Version Crimson-16.7.1) to see if that helps, but no change.

I'm using the following to start mining:

```
ethminer -G --opencl-device 1 -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/0xD...48e/VarlicGPU1
```

Trying to force mining from device 1 which is one of the Radeon cards. ethminer reports that it is using the Intel card, even though that is device 0.

"Found suitable OpenCL device [Intel(R) HD Graphics 530]"

Would be great if anyone has any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Try placing the --opencl-device 1 at the end of the command so it looks something like this:

```
ethminer -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/0xD...48e/VarlicGPU1 -G --opencl-device 1
```

Also if you want to configure ethminer to use both RX480 cards then you can try this:

```
ethminer -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/WalletAddress/WorkerName -G --opencl-device 1,2
```

Hope that helps

---

On a slight side note, the latest amd drivers for the RX400 series are "Crimson ReLive 16.12.2"

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. I changed to Claymore's dual miner, you can set it to Eth only, but it supposedly is no less efficient to enable dual mining. 16.12.2 is recommended for claymore

Answer (score -1):

Try `-G --opencl-platform 1`. It worked for me.